# WebBrowser blocks sliding in PivotControl

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, pivot

I have PivotControl in my application and in some of pivotItems WebBrowser.
I noticed that WebBrowser blocks sliding to next pivots. I'm not sure if this is ok, because
other pivots slides and that one with WebBrowser doesn't, and that can be confusing. Is this 
behavior correct? Is there way to solve this? (maybe little hack)

here is my xaml code:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY PIVOT">
    <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
        <TextBlock Text="First Pivot" />
    </controls:PivotItem> 
    <controls:PivotItem Header="second">
        <TextBlock Text="Second Pivot" />
    </controls:PivotItem>       
    <controls:PivotItem Header="third">
        <phone:WebBrowser Source="http://www.stackoverflow.com" />
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct behavior.

`WebBrowser` does that to enable Horizontal scrolling for web pages.

That is why it is not advisable to put such controls in a `Pivot`. For example, try putting a `Map` control inside a `Pivot`.

I recommend you take your `WebBrowser` out of `Pivot` and put it in a separate page.

Answer (score 4):

It's not suggested to include controls that take input gestures themselves (such as the `Map` or `WebBrowser` controls) inside a `Pivot` or `Panorama` for this very reason. However, there is a post about [Preventing the Pivot or Panorama controls from scrolling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) that should give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is a correct behaviour, because it severes the usability of those two controls. The fact that WebBrowser does that is irrelevant, because the web page CAN DISABLE horizontal scroling via  tags, and force the renderer to reflow the document so it always fits the screen. In that case, the WebBrowser has completely no reason to consume the horiz-swipes that the Pivot needs.

I have already solved similar issue few months ago in one app, and with Pivot - it is circumventable. I've written on that here: [Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser control swallows manipulation events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275120/windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control-swallows-manipulation-events/7391698#7391698) and also in that post is another link to another mine.. sorry, it's split up a bit, I didn't have time to put it in one place.

If I recall properly, the basic trick was to use GestureListener over the WebBrowser, listen to flicks and force Pivot.SelectedIndex++/-- accordingly. It will allow to flick&move, but will NOT provide the Pivot-y animation of dragging a page and then snapping to the next/prev page. For this animation, another trick is needed and IIRC that mine other post is about that

Please note: The GestureListener, not the manipulation events!!! those are extinguished (API 7.0, 7.1, 7.5rc) by the WebBrowser (in 7.1+ - by the internal PanZoomContainer, in 7.0 - they were simply silenced by TileHost)! GestureListener listens "on some other source" of events and sees everything even if mani-events are dead. On 7.1+ it is possible to hack into the WebBrowser and hijack use mani-events, too, but its harder (it also is in the other post of mine, I think)