# pivot with in Panorma ....swipe both together

Tags: windows-phone-7

when i use pivot with in the panorama .pivot are  used as a gallery view. i want to move pivot when i swipe it .but the problem is this because of both panorama and pivot are the same gesture event so both are they move . 
i want swipe only my pivot view .

I would like some sample code or any other suggestion to do this.
 so please give me a solution for doing this and 
also give me a link where i easily understand this. Thanx in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to put a Pivot inside of a Panorama.  The gesture issue being just one of the reasons why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a Pivot in a Panorama control. End of discussion.

Comment: any suggetion for achiving gallery view in panorama .

Comment: Do you mean like the Picture Hub? Otherwise I think you misunderstood what the Panorama Control is for. It's a entry control, meant to give a quick overview, and list a menu. Deeper interaction should be on other pages.

Comment: That doesn't even remotely make sense.

Comment: in my project four panorama item .home ,category,search,favourite......in home i show one listbox which has bind ,its has two view in 0'th index one pivot view to show gallery ..and another index are only show list of article ....so gallery is need of my project..

Comment: You should move the gallery to a separate sub-page the user navigate to. It shouldn't be part of your Pivot. You completely misunderstood how to design for the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is achievable, because I've already solved similar issues with having WebBrowser control inside a custom horizontal-scrollable overview container like Pivot/Panorama, but believe me, it is NOT worth it. I've had to dig very deep into the visualstructure of the controls and attach my own manipulation-handlers to their viscera, manually choose which horiz/verti events to pass and which to cancel, and so on. This is not so easy, takes a lot of time, and doesn't guarantee that on the end you will have something behaving in a way you wanted to achieve in the first place. If you are not bound by some contract to preserve the shape of the UI, please, drop the idea and redesign your UI, just to save on your sanity and nerves.

But, if you are already insane or really want to dig where noone should, start on analysing your UI as a two rectangles: large pano and small pivo, and think which part should behave how on different possible touches/h-v swipes/h-v pans/pinches/so on. Write it down just to for reference, or soon you will probably start making small mistakes that will interfere with your understaning of the flow of the events.

I've checked the version I have, and "my" Panorama uses internally the UIElement.ManipulationXXXX events. In that case:

Display visualtrees of your UI and try attaching manipulation-events to every control. In those events, write/log which control's which handler was invoked. Then make some swipe/scroll on your APP and observe events. Analyze how they were bubbling and try cancelling (e.Handled=true) the manipulation-completed and/or manipulation-delta events somewhere between pivot and panorama. Your goal is to have the panorama see that e.Handled=true, while your pivot must see e.Handled=false. Your Pivot will probably see the event sooner than the Pano, so that point should be relatively easy.

If it fails to work, then you should check your version of the Pano, and check how it detects movements. If, for example, it uses the GestureListener - try the same trick with it. Etc.

And remember, you can always make your own horizontal-overwiew-container that will look like Pano, behave like Pano, and that will work with Pivo better - because it will be your code and you will tell it what and when to move. if you want to go this way, start on google and check all the preliminary Panorama previews that random people have published before that control was published by MS.

Comment: Can you share your solution for the WebBrowser + horizontal-scrollable container?

Comment: Try using http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/ that was build by Colin using some details I've described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7347448/717732 ; I'm sorry but I cannot fetch my original code currently